# How to convert cURL to http post in Flutter

Tags: curl, flutter, dart

I have a Rest API successfully running and can make curl post as:

```
curl -X POST "{{baseURL}}/api/auth/login" -H "accept: application/json" -H "Content-Type: application/json-patch+json" -d "{ \"nick\": \"string"\", \"password\": \"string\"}"
```

My wish is to write a code that will do the exact job as above command, I mean how to decode/encode stuff in proper way. This is what I got so far:

```
Future<http.Response> postRequest (String nick, String password) async {
  var url ='{{baseURL}}/api/auth/login';
  var body = jsonEncode({ "nick": "$nick", "password": "$password"});

  print("Body: " + body);

  http.post(url,
    headers: {"accept": "application/json","Content-Type": "application/json- 
     patch+json"},
    body: body
  ).then((http.Response response) {
 });
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: instead of encoded json for the body.type , try it with a string in the body.    ie JSON obj -> toString

Answer (score 14, accepted):

There's no need to use `then` inside an `async` function - it's typically easier and more readable to use `await`. I assume you don't really want to return the `Response` and leave it to the caller to handle that. Since your accept is set to JSON, you may as well immediately decode the response and return the parsed tree (or some part of it) - but only a suggestion.

(I've corrected style and formatting a bit.)

Try this:

```
Future<Map<String, dynamic>> postRequest(String nick, String password) async {
  // todo - fix baseUrl
  var url = '{{baseURL}}/api/auth/login';
  var body = json.encode({
    'nick': nick,
    'password': password,
  });

  print('Body: $body');

  var response = await http.post(
    url,
    headers: {
      'accept': 'application/json',
      'Content-Type': 'application/json-patch+json',
    },
    body: body,
  );

  // todo - handle non-200 status code, etc

  return json.decode(response.body);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Richard! You saved my day :)

Answer (score 1):

```
var map = new Map<String, dynamic>();
map["nick"] = nick;
map["password"] = password;
http.post(url, body: map);
```

Answer (score 0):

How to post for like this curl
`enter code here`$ curl -s -X POST 
-d '{"version": "5c7d5dc6dd8bf75c1acaa8565754288755b66206b55cca93cb72c9bf15ccaa", "input": {"text": "Alice"}}' 
-H "Authorization: Token 89021c58b3c579dfyr144225680658e107f55" 
-H 'Content-Type: application/json' 
https://api.replicate.com/v1/predictions